# Item Content not Scrolling automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `feature content slider` which uses `JQuery UI tabs`. And when the active tab set into an item `li` it shows the picture in the bigger div besides it. What Im trying to do is to find a way where in the `item list` auto scroll or the item with the active class will be always shown in front.
here is a working sample -->  http://jsfiddle.net/aceMunim/HT7se/

and i have also tried implementing `SmoothDivScroll` and `scrollable` in JQuery documentation but it conflicts with the current JQuery lib installed or it does not work.

Comment: For using `SmoothDivScroll` use `jQuery.noConflict()`

Comment: I did that too. But unfortunately it does not do the trick

Answer (score 0):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9GXvm/)

```
#featured .ui-tabs-panel {
    width:340px;
    ....
}
```

Comment: it does not auto scroll still. there has not been any changes at all :) except for the panel width ofcourse